# Is it possible to create a NFA that accepts only n*"a" or n*"b" inputs?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I'd like to create a NFA that accepts only inputs like "aaaaa";"a";"bb";"bbb", but not like "aab";"aabaa".
Is the even possible? As far as I understand NFA is processing a superspositon of all sub-inputs. So then, if given automaton accepts "a" or "b", it would always accept "ab" just like it accepts "b". Is there a way around, am I missing something?

[image]

Would it work? After reading n*'a' and then 'b' the automaton leaves accepting state but in the same time it is entering another accepting state.

Comment: One could argue that your picture represents a *deterministic* finite automaton since there are no possible choices for a given input. Given input $aaa$, for instance, it goes from the start state to the upper accept state and stays there for the rest of the input. On the other hand, given $ab$ it goes from start state, to the upper state and thereafter is stuck, since there is no move available when seeing the $b$ part of the input.

Comment: (Yeah, I know that the set of NFAs includes the set of DFAs.)

Comment: If 'ab' is inserted it should consume 'a', go to the upper state then consume 'b' and break upper state and go to the lower state in parallel. And I want to create an automaton that is not in accepting state after reading 'ab' - this picteure is an attachment for the discussion below.

Comment: It seems you don't quite understand how automata work, please try to read and practice on the definition and examples of different automata. In your automaton, if you read $aaa$, you will reach the upper state; if you then read $b$ after reading $aaa$, you will not reach the lower state, because there is no transition between both states. Instead, since there is no transition labeled by $b$ exiting from the upper state, the automaton will halt and reject the word $aaab$. That means your automaton is correct (except if $n$ can be zero, if so, the start state must be final).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

Considering regular expression and NFA have the same power (source [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)), your question amounts to asking if there is such a regular expression.

So the regular expression would be /a*|b*/.

As for a NFA doing such a thing, here is an [article](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html) describing how to go from regex to NFA.

In the article about regex to NFA, there is a section at the end explaining about metacharacter \$ for end of string. An actual regex for your problem would then be /^(a*|b*)$/ .

Comment: But isn't [a*|b*] expression maching strings like 'aabb'? Then I need an expression that would accept 'aa' but no 'aab'.

Comment: @KacperOgórek $a^*|b^*$ means either a word of $a^*$ or a word of $b^*$, not a mix of both.

Comment: No this regex only matches the empty string "", "a" or "aa", ... or "b" or "bb" ... but not a mix of a and b

Comment: Yes, but after implementing the NFA is in accepting state after reading such string. Im attaching my implementation in another comment thread below.

Comment: Can you edit your post to put the implementation there please ?

Comment: Yes, sure. It is done.

Comment: Ok, after seeing your NFA, your states for A and B are accepting states, which they shouldn't be, that's why it matches the string, because there isn't any more test. You need to add one more state with a transition from the states A and B that will act as the accepting state. The transition will be triggered if it reached the end of the string.

Comment: Even if I introduced some terminator ';', a string 'aab;' would still be accepted as 'b;'. Then how do I know whether there was an 'a' proceeding the b?

Comment: If you introduce a terminator ';', then you have a transition from the state A to the accepting state when ';' is read. Same for B. But again, states A and B must not be accepting, it seems to me that your troubles comes from A and B being accepting.